# How can I test changing Azure service configuration settings at runtime locally?

Tags: azure, azure-configuration, azure-compute-emulator

I am writing our Azure app to use Azure service configuration settings so we can change it in real time. I can test it by deploying and then changing them in the Azure web portal.

How do I allow changing service configuration in real time on my local azure compute emulator?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to update the service configuration you need to modify the *.cscfg file and execute csrun.exe (in *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator*):

```
csrun.exe /update:<deployment-id>;<service-configuration-file>
```

Note that this seems to work only when running the application without debugger.

I recently blogged about this here: [Controlling your instances in the Windows Azure Compute Emulator](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/controlling-your-instances-in-the-windows-azure-compute-emulator/) (look under *Handling the RoleEnvironment.Changing event in the emulator*).

Comment: Great. Thanks for that I was totally unaware of it. Now if I could just manage to get my membership connection string stored in service configuration it would be a good week :)

Comment: Sorry for the pile-on. Is there anyway I can change value for just one key in my configuration file from my role itself? My guess is not, but I wanted to make sure of that.

Comment: @GraemeMiller, I wroted a detailed blog post on how you can store the connection string for your membership provider in the service configuration: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/asp-net-universal-providers-and-the-windows-azure-service-configuration/

Comment: @GauravMantri, well you can simply change one value in the cscfg file and execute csrun.exe (even though this will use the whole cscfg file)

Comment: WOW! That is amazingly helpful. Both my major Azure issues resolved. Your blog has gone to the top of my reading list!